# How to configure mysql with gearman?

Tags: mysql, configure, gearman

I have installed gearman in my PC.Also its working fine.But as of now its was non persistence storage, but i need to make as a persistence storage.Then i have plan to configure mysql into gearman,but i did't able to do.I don't know how to configure.
If any one know kindly response with your link.If any example program it could be much better.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use libdrizzle (which I think is in the gearman packages by default) as the client to access your mysql database.

Use a command like this to start the gearman server and you should have persistent queues.
/gearmand -q libdrizzle 
--libdrizzle-host=10.1.1.1 
--libdrizzle-user=gearman 
--libdrizzle-password=secret 
--libdrizzle-db=some_db 
--libdrizzle-table=gearman_queue 
--libdrizzle-mysql